# comorbidity package: How to calculate Charlson Comorbidity Index by ID?

Tags: r

I've been having some issues with the "comorbidity" package since updated R to version 3.6.1 and RStudio to version 1.2.5001.

I'd like to calculate the Charlson Comorbidity Index (CCI) by ID but since updating R I keep getting the following warning:

```
#Create data frame
df <- data.frame(
  "ID" = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"),
  "ICD10" = c("A41.9","G92","K52.9","N30.00","N20.0","R10.9","Z95.5","E78.5","I63.9","R47.81","Z87.891"),
  "NumEncounters" = rep(1, times = 11)
)

#Calculate CCI
ccm_test <- comorbidity(x=df, id="ID", code="ICD10", score="charlson", icd = "icd10", 
                        assign0=TRUE, tidy.codes=TRUE)

#Warning message appears
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
Warning messages:
1: In data.table::melt(loc, value.name = code) :
  The melt generic in data.table has been passed a list and will attempt to redirect to the relevant reshape2 method; please note that reshape2 is deprecated, and this redirection is now deprecated as well. To continue using melt methods from reshape2 while both libraries are attached, e.g. melt.list, you can prepend the namespace like reshape2::melt(loc). In the next version, this warning will become an error.
2: In `[.data.table`(merge(x, loc, all.x = TRUE, allow.cartesian = TRUE),  :
  Column 'code' does not exist to remove
```

The output is now one row with the aggregated CCI for all of my IDs. How can I get my code back to working normally like it was prior to the updates?

Comment: Seems like a package bug. Try contacting `maintainer("comorbidity")`.

Comment: perhaps needs to be 'id' and 'code' instead of 'ID' and 'ICD10' - see this recent github issue: https://github.com/ellessenne/comorbidity/issues/20 or maybe check the latest development version